# Either saving to or reading from an XML file is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Using Tkinter I have programmed a window that displays information, and links to files, based on an xml file.

When saving to the xml file it saves as:

`<Files>C:\Users\-\Documents\_Programming\Example.txt<File /></Files>`
Instead of:
`<Files><File>C:\Users\-\Documents\Programming\Example1.txt</File></Files>`
which works.

As a result, other parts of the code see the text as a 'NoneType' and thus can't use it.

**How can I change the reading of the xml file or the saving to the xml file that will allow the program to function?**

> Entire code: https://pastebin.com/0BwkaJhz

*I apologise for a lack of commenting*

## This section of code should take user-input information and write to an existing .xml file

```
      def done(self):
        sessions_not_exist = True
        for element in self.student:
            if element.tag == 'Sessions':
                sessions_not_exist = False

        if sessions_not_exist == True:
            sessions = et.SubElement(self.student, "Sessions")
            tree.write(data_file)

        for element in self.student:
            if element.tag == 'Sessions':
                new_session = et.SubElement(element, "Session")

                new_session_date = et.SubElement(new_session, 'Date')
                new_session_date.text = self.date_entry.get()

                new_session_description = et.SubElement(new_session, 'Description')
                new_session_description.text = self.description_entry.get()


                new_session_files = et.SubElement(new_session, "Files")
                tree.write(data_file)

                
                for file in self.files:
                    new_session_file = et.SubElement(new_session_files, "File")
                    new_session_files.text = file
                    tree.write(data_file)
```

## This section of code looks at the xml file and returns the data

```
      def find_data(self):
        for student in tree.findall('Student'):
            for element in student:
                if element.tag == "Name" and element.text == self.studentX:
                    student_id = student.attrib['id']
                    self.student_exact = student
                else:
                    break

        
        session_data_list = []
        for element in self.student_exact:
            
            if element.tag == "Sessions":
                for session in element:                    
                    single_session = []
                    sessions_files = []
                    for child in session:
                        print(f"{child.tag}:   {child}")                        
                        if child.tag == 'Files':                           
                            for file in child:
                                sessions_files.append(file.text)
                                self.allFiles.append(file.text)
                            single_session.append(sessions_files)                            
                        else:
                            single_session.append(child.text)
                    session_data_list.append(single_session)

        return session_data_list
```

## The xml file/code (sorry for poor layout):

`<root><Student id="1"><Name>Ruby</Name><Sessions><Session><Date>12/03/18</Date><Description>Measurement Problems and Long Division</Description><Files><File>C:\Users\Hazzb.HARRY-PC\Desktop\testing\test.py</File></Files></Session><Session><Date>26/03/18</Date<Description>Symmetry</Description></Session><Session><Date>xx.xx.xx</Date><Description>XXXXXX</Description><Files><File>C:\Users\Hazzb.HARRY-PC\PycharmProjects\Mother's Tutoring\oioi.txt</File><File>C:\Users\Hazzb.HARRY-PC\Desktop\testing\This File.txt</File></Files></Session><Session><Date>23/11/2019</Date><Description>Example</Description><Files>C:\Users\Hazzb.HARRY-PC\Documents\_Programming\ArtExample.txt<File /></Files></Session></Sessions></Student></root>`

Comment: well, you're not telling us where `data_file` is defined and what's the content. I think this is relevant to get what's the problem here.

Comment: @Chobeat The data_file was the .xml file which I have shown. But, no matter, the problem is resolved. Furthermore, I did link the pastebin that shows all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your `done` function is the culprit

```
new_session_files.text = file
```

Change that to

```
new_session_file.text = file
```

Secondly, in your `done` function, there are multiple `tree.write(data_file)`, you need only have to do that once. At the end when you are done with updating the tree completely.